# Google App Engine providing indention error with Python

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am trying to host locally a simple python script using Google App Engine. Instead of showing a form, the page keeps loading blank. In terminal, it says "IndentationError: expected an indented block" for line 13. I can't find an indention error there. What could be the problem?

```
import webapp2

form = """
<form method="post" action="/testform">
    <input name="q"> <input type="submit">
</form>
"""

class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):

class TestHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        q=self.request.get("q") 
        self.response.out.write(q)

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage),
                              ('/testform', TestHandler)],
                             debug=True)
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an OP coding error (empty method) and will hardly be of help for others

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
```

has nothing after it. It needs something, even if it's just a `pass` statement.

Line 13 is the first line with text immediately after it, and the error message said it was expecting indented text there. Looking just before there would show you where the expected indentation came from.